# Angular 14 project installation

Tags: node.js, angular, node-modules, angular14

I am facing the following issue. Error posted down. Please share your answer I am waiting for valuable feedback.

```
DEPRECATED: The 'defaultProject' workspace option has been deprecated. The project to use will be determined from the current working directory.
Your global Angular CLI version (15.0.4) is greater than your local version (11.2.19). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
\ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...node:internal/crypto/hash:71
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
                  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Sonal.D\runner\krushna_m-runner_web_admin-1241444b7c08\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\Sonal.D\runner\krushna_m-runner_web_admin-1241444b7c08\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (C:\Users\Sonal.D\runner\krushna_m-runner_web_admin-1241444b7c08\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at C:\Users\Sonal.D\runner\krushna_m-runner_web_admin-1241444b7c08\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5
    at C:\Users\Sonal.D\runner\krushna_m-runner_web_admin-1241444b7c08\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12
    at C:\Users\Sonal.D\runner\krushna_m-runner_web_admin-1241444b7c08\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\Sonal.D\runner\krushna_m-runner_web_admin-1241444b7c08\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\Sonal.D\runner\krushna_m-runner_web_admin-1241444b7c08\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
    at C:\Users\Sonal.D\runner\krushna_m-runner_web_admin-1241444b7c08\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:236:3
    at context.callback (C:\Users\Sonal.D\runner\krushna_m-runner_web_admin-1241444b7c08\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at C:\Users\Sonal.D\runner\krushna_m-runner_web_admin-1241444b7c08\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:59:71
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v18.12.1

C:\Users\Sonal.D\runner\krushna_m-runner_web_admin-1241444b7c08>export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I tried these:-

1. Node version uninstall and install.
2. cli version uninstall and install.

The following commands are used:-

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

If you try ng --version with angular cli 14, you will get that error. Please use ng version instead.

Comment: Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

Comment: This is Error Please help

Comment: Why do you create a project inside another project?